# Problemas al ejecutar una consulta SQL con C #

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, visual-studio

Buenas lo que ocurre es que la consulta usando workbench me funciona y al usar el MySqlCommand usando por ejemplo una consulta regular de select * from me lee los datos y me permite jugar con ellos por ejemplo usandolos en un datagrid view el problema es que cuando intento hacer la consulta usando un Where donde el dato para compara es un string no me genera la consulta. Como podria hacer?

Este es el codigo:

```
MySqlCommand sqlpedpen = new MySqlCommand("select ped_price as Precio, ped_status as Estado, cli_phone as Telefono, date_reg as Fecha, ped_type as Tipo, ped_entrega as Direccion from sushi2home.pedidos where ped_status = Enviado", mysqlCon);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que no estás poniendo el valor del WHERE (`Enviado`) entre comillas simples, entonces lo trata como una columna más y no como un valor.

Debes ponerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
"select ped_price as Precio, ped_status as Estado, cli_phone as Telefono, date_reg as Fecha, ped_type as Tipo, ped_entrega as Direccion from sushi2home.pedidos where ped_status = 'Enviado'"
```

Answer (score 2):

Tendrias que usar parametros

```
string query = "select ped_price as Precio, ped_status as Estado, cli_phone as Telefono, date_reg as Fecha, ped_type as Tipo, ped_entrega as Direccion from sushi2home.pedidos where ped_status = ?status";
MySqlCommand sqlpedpen = new MySqlCommand(query , mysqlCon);
sqlpedpen.Parameters.AddWithValue("?status", "Enviado");
```

Asi puedes asignar el valor y poder cambiarlo desde codigo sin necesidad de concatenar en el string el valor

Nota: igualmente recuerda que las cadena de string deben ir entre comillas simples